# Add a datafile type reader to paraview using pvpython

Tags: python, vtk, paraview, pvpython

I'm aware that you can [add readers for different datafile types](http://paraview.org/Wiki/Writing_ParaView_Readers) to paraview, however, that all talks about doing a bunch of VTK stuff in c++ and (maybe worse) re-compiling paraview to make it aware of your datafile format.  On the other hand, [paraview also supports scripting in python](http://paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Python_Scripting).  Maybe it is my lack of familiarity with VTK, but, to me it looks like I can only *manipulate* VTK objects from pvpython.  Is there any way to dynamically add a reader to paraview using pvpython?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a "Python Programmable Filter. Refer to [ParaView Wiki](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_Programmable_Filter). This [wiki page](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Simple_ParaView_3_Python_Filters#CSV_Reader_.28Source.29) shows how to write a CSV reader in Python.

Answer (score 0):

As time has passed, ParaView has new options to achieve this.
It's worth looking at the recently added [Python Algorithm](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/ReferenceManual/pythonProgrammableFilter.html#python-algorithm) feature in ParaView.
[Examples](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/blob/master/Examples/Plugins/PythonAlgorithm/PythonAlgorithmExamples.py) are given in the source code.